# debmake - install has no effect on one file pointed in rules-file

Tags: debian, installation, dpkg

I have a rules-file that says:

```
override_dh_auto_install:
    install -D -m 0755 compiled_app $$(pwd)/debian/myapp/opt/myapp/compiled_app 
    install -D -m 0755 Run/script $(pwd)/debian/myapp/opt/myapp/script
```

the file script has:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
sudo ./compiled_app
```

Unfortunately this file is not installed to target directory when using `debuild`

If i use the command from the rules-file in commandline the file is copied to targer folder.

Anyone can give me a hint what I am doing wrong?

If I gave not enough information, please tell me.

thanks alot

Comment: It is very very very very bad practice to do what you are doing. `sudo` works maybe on your distribution because you are an admin. Never require human intervention on installation scripts. You do no need `sudo`. the installation is done in root. If you program need root permission, give them a system user and group.  If you build a package, you should be more integrated to the system, or it will be a mess.

Comment: ok.. got that.. does debuild avoid usage of scripts with sudo? could that be the reason why the install-command have no effect? TY